# The restriction of a discontinuous linear functional to any open set is surjective.

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification, topological-vector-spaces

> **Problem.** Let $X$ be a topological vector space and $f:X\to\mathbb{K}$ a linear mapping. Prove that if $f$ is discontinuous, then $f(A)=\mathbb{K}$ for all nonempty open set $A\subset X$.

I'd like to know if the solution below is correct.

**Solution.**

Let $A\subset X$ be a nonempty open set and $a\in A$. Then, $A=a+V$ where $V$ is a neighborhood of $0$. Let $W$ be a balanced neighborhood of $0$ such that $W\subset V$.

Since $f$ is discontinuous, there exist $\varepsilon>0$ such that $f(U)\not\subset B(0,\varepsilon)$ for all neighborhood $U$ of $0$.

Claim 1: $f(W)$ is unbounded.
*Proof:* If $f(W)$ is bounded, then there exist $r>0$ such that $f(W)\subset B(0,r)$. Taking $U=\frac{\varepsilon}{r} W$ we obtain
$f(U)= \frac{\varepsilon}{r}f(W)\subset \frac{\varepsilon}{r}B(0,r)= B(0,\varepsilon),$
a contradiction.

Claim 2: $\mathbb{K}\subset f(W)$.
*Proof:* Take $\alpha\in\mathbb{K}$. From Claim 1, there exist $w\in W$ such that $|f(w)|>|\alpha|$. Taking $\beta=\frac{\alpha}{f(w)}$ we conclude that $f(\beta w)=\alpha$ and $\beta w\in W$ (because $|\beta|<1$ and $W$ is balanced). Thus $\alpha\in f(W)$.

It follows from Claim 2 that

$$\mathbb{K}=f(a)+\mathbb{K}\subset f(a)+f(W)\subset f(a)+f(V)=f(a+V)=f(A).$$

Thanks.

Comment: Looks good to me .You didn't define K. Are you assuming that V is  a real or complex space and that K is the scalars (i.e. R or C)?

Comment: @user254665 Thank you. Yes, K = R or C.